# A train full of Warlords

Tags: story-identification

I am sure I read this story in an collection of shorts many years ago. Possibly not the correct title but that is the basis of the tale. A fast moving train with a bunch of warlords on it.

Comment: Do you remember anything at all that happens in the story?

Comment: Were they allies?  Rivals?  On the same side?  Was the story about how they interacted, or were they a McGuffin?

Comment: *'A Train Full of Warlords' tells of a family in the aftermath of a tragedy and the ways in which each is dealing with it.*; http://wyrdbritain.blogspot.com/2016/07/a-touch-of-chill.html